# Do spreadsheet formulas work on data imported by importhtml/xml?

Tags: google-sheets

I use `importhtml` to receive data from an website. Now i try to evaluate this data with an formula from my Spreadsheet. 
I want to find the max value of the imported data.
I use `=max()` for that.

Is it possible that imported data (using importxml, importhtml, google finance)  can not be further access / manipulated?

Code:
`=INDEX(importhtml("http://www.cboe.com/data/current-market-statistics";"table";0);;5)`

Spreadsheet formula: `=max()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=max(INDEX(importhtml("http://www.cboe.com/data/current-market-statistics";"table";0);;5))
```

should work (and return `1.07` at the moment).

Comment: this returns 43374. There is probably an format issue. How i can i find out if thats the case? Iam from germany btw so "." equals "," . i tried also `=substitute(max(INDEX(importhtml("http://www.cboe.com/data/current-market-statistics";"table";0);;5)) ) `

Comment: I found a solution to this problem. It´s a formatting issue ( as guessed ). E.g. if you import data from an US website and your from Germany  you have to set your location settings to "United Kingdom". Then "." will equal ",".